# .NET Library/Book for Crowd Simulation

Tags: .net, artificial-intelligence, simulation

I've been tasked with creating a simulation of people moving around.  It could be a bunch of people walking through a restaurant or exiting a school.  Searching around, I've found a bunch A* related stuff which is fine for one person but I will have a bunch.  Is there a standard library people use for this stuff?  Or a kind of algorithm I should look at?  Or a book that will get me going?

Comment: Just curious, what's the simulation for exactly? Interesting problem.

Comment: i guess the guy is in the games industry.

Comment: Sadly, this isn't for games.  If I ever get share the work, I'll definitely post a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone.  I believe the best article I've found is also written by Craig Reynolds on the same site as the one @x0n [sited](http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/).  If you click the links, there are a bunch of simple java applets that give examples for his paper.

There were a number of websites that suggested the [OpenSteer](http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/) library which is written in C++.  I finally found [SharpSteer](http://sharpsteer.codeplex.com/) which takes the same library and ports it to C#.  They have a bunch of great demos written for XNA.

Answer (score 5):

I am by no means an AI guy, but I even I could understand this:

http://www.red3d.com/cwr/boids/

I found it a great starting point for emergent behaviour alogorthims and naturalistic movement/flocking. The entry page here is oriented around flying animals, but there are many links at the foot of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Few games really pull off crowds well, but Assassin's Creed was pretty impressive. Each person had some (basic) objectives like begging for money, carrying pots to the marketplace, walking in a group etc. and all of this welded into a really impressive (compared to other games) simulation of a crowd.

Here is an article that pulls together various aspects of modeling crowds with links to various research papers:
[Simulating Crowd Flow Dynamics](http://aigamedev.com/open/article/simulating-crowd-flow-dynamics/)

Answer (score 2):

The  repast toolkit ( http://repast.sourceforge.net/repast_3/index.html ) has a .Net implementation which you can download from http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=1703&package_id=1655 .

More in general you want to look for "Agent Based Modeling" see http://jasss.soc.surrey.ac.uk/12/2/2.html or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABM_Software_Comparison

Answer (score 1):

You might [try Googling](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&hs=fPE&q=ages+of+empires+algorithm&btnG=Search) some of your favorite games that do this. For example, here are [two interesting](http://books.google.com/books?id=1hwR5gIq0I8C&pg=PA228&lpg=PA228&dq=ages+of+empires+algorithm&source=bl&ots=nmDhO5uGy3&sig=dRN1k1Ves1llmWaiD3c9pCMXoXI&hl=en&ei=h-MWSvjbJp2xtgf395zfDA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1) [results](http://artho.com/age/pathfinding.html) for [Ages of Empires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Empires).